# Converting NVARCHAR-0.0075 to DECIMALSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to convert a column having  a `nvarchar` value like -0.0075 to decimal like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [TwilioSmsLogs] ADD Price_New decimal(18,5)

UPDATE [TwilioSmsLogs]
SET Price_New = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,5), ISNULL(Price,0))

ALTER TABLE [TwilioSmsLogs] DROP COLUMN Price

EXEC sp_RENAME 'TwilioSmsLogs.Price_New' , 'Price', 'COLUMN'
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query fix my problem

```
update [TwilioSmsLogs]
set Price_New = convert(decimal(18,5), round(ISNULL(Price,0),5))
```